# How to run regression on a Taguchi design?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, experiment-design, minitab

I'm trying to run a regression analysis on a Taguchi design. I have five categorical control factors, one of them with two levels and the other four with three levels.

I want to generate a regression equation either based on the control factors without the levels or with the optimal levels for each factor. Is this possible?

Comment: 1. This will be more easily done using the ANOVA format/framework, though mathematically ANOVA and regression are equivalent. 2. What do you mean by "based on the control factors without the levels"?  3. If you use just the optimal level for each factor you'll have no way to assign coefficients. Regression requires that the factors have the opportunity to vary, so you can show how the outcome varies with them.